# Issue building Gradle project: error message "functional test classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput"

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to build a Gradle project but when I build the project with `gradle clean build` I get the following error message:

> Could not get unknown property 'classesDirs' for functional test classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput

How can I fix my build?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me because I wasn't using the right version of Gradle. The project required Gradle 4.8 but I was inadvertently using Gradle 2.14. I fixed it by upgrading to Gradle 4.8. Note that using Gradle wrapper also works.